# Rendering two columns with AngularJS and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to render with Bootstrap and AngularJS data in two or more columns.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in experiences_days | orderBy: 'created_at':true | limitTo:totalDisplayed track by x._id" ng-cloak>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4">
            {{x}}
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

It appears only among themselves. I need the two data next to each other, from left to right.

However here is an example:

http://codepen.io/xmercix/pen/dGpLeY

Comment: On a side note, you realize that you're repeating everything inside the outer `div`, right? So obviously you get multiple `container`s, with multiple `row`s, etc...

Comment: Jup I am getting multiply container and row?

Comment: Please include a full but minimal repro. See these pages for help: [mcve]. Without it, we'd be *guessing* at the solution (which, note to self, we should not do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the ng-repeat to the div with col-md-x class

```
<div ng-cloak>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="x in experiences_days | orderBy: 'created_at':true | limitTo:totalDisplayed track by x._id">
            {{data}}
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

container and row classes will force your next div into the next line, which is not the behavior you want as it seems.
by having col-md-4 in your inner div, you will have 3 items in each line.

Comment: Thats it! Many thanx!